# Compare values from two Arrays PHP

Tags: php, levenshtein-distance

I have two Arrays with Objects in it. I want to compare each property of the array with each other.

```
function compare ($array1, $array2)
{
        $uniqueArray = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++)
        {
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($array2); $j++)
            {
                if(levenshtein($array1[$i]->getCompany(), $array2[$j]-     >getCompany() > 0 || levenshtein($array1[$i]->getCompany(), $array2[$j]->getCompany()) < 3))
                {
                    //add values to $unqiueArray    
                }
            }
        }
        print_r($uniqueArray);
}
```

I'm not sure if my code is right. The iteration over the arrays and then the compare is that the right approach?

Object Properties:

```
private $_company;
private $_firstname;
private $_sirname;
private $_street;
private $_streetnumber;
private $_plz;
private $_place;
```

All prperties are strings.

Comment: can you also update your question with object properties?

Comment: here are the properties

Comment: Can a php array actually hold an instance of a class so that you can call methods like getCompany()? Im only asking because Im unsure of this myself.

Comment: yes, i have tested it.

Comment: Your approach is correct in my opinion so far, vote up for that, my only advice before comparing or using any kind of method try to print your both array content in the nested `for loop` to see if you at all get some identical outputs. if so, then take 2 values and levenstein them in your if statement out of the nested `for loop` to see if it works. Finally you can but the puzzles together.

Comment: thanks for your advice. it works fine with levenshtein but how can i put the right values in $uniqueArray? my code: `if (levenshtein($array1[$i]->getCompany(), $array2[$j]->getCompany()) < 3){
     $uniqueArray [] = $array1[$i];
    }`
But that put 33 values to it. that are too many. in my two arrays are only 15 objects.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use `for (expr1; expr2; expr3)` for iterating arrays; it's better to use `foreach (array_expression as $value)`
Also, you are comparing every element on array1 with every element on array2, but if there's a match you compare them again later.
Try something like this

```
foreach($array1 as $k1 => $v1) {
    foreach($array2 as $k2 => $v2) {
        if(your_condition()) {
            $uniqueArray[] = $v1;
            unset($array2[$k2])
        }
    }
}
```

Or maybe do some research on `array_uintersect` or `array_walk`

Comment: thanks so far! when i want to add both values to $uniqueArray im adding $uniqueArray[] = $v2; to the code right?

Comment: yes. `[]` adds elements to an array and $v2 is the value of the second array

Answer (score 0):

- In the `if`, one parenthesis is mis-placed, which probably is the main problem and does unexpected results.
- `levenstein` is not a trivial operation, you shouldn't do it two times just to compare it, it's better to store the result in a variable.
- Without more details about the input and expected output, it's impossible to help you more.

Here is the code fixed.

```
function compare ($array1, $array2)
{
        $uniqueArray = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++)
        {
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($array2); $j++)
            {
                $companyNamesLevenstein = levenshtein($array1[$i]->getCompany(), $array2[$j]->getCompany());
                if($companyNamesLevenstein > 0 || $companyNamesLevenstein < 3)
                {
                    $uniqueArray [] = $array1[$i];  
                }
            }
        }
        print_r($uniqueArray);
}
```